# Why does my Access report keep crashing after adding some simple VBA code?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access report that uses an option group to give 2 options of sorting - by job_date and by FGNumber. However, it keeps crashing when I go to use another program and then come back to the report.

I get the error message "Access has stopped working..." and then it restarts

Is there something wrong with my VBA code?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Report_Load()

    Me.OrderBy = "job_date"
    Me.Frame367 = 1

End Sub

Private Sub Frame367_Click()

    If Me.Frame367 = 1 Then
        Me.OrderBy = "job_date"
    Else
        Me.OrderBy = "FGNumber"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you meant by crashing?

Comment: I get the error message "Access has stopped working..." and then it restarts.